# Autofill Elements WKWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview, autofill

I was wondering if it would be possible to autofill elements in the WKWebView? Or like auto click on them or something like that.

I want to make a script that autofill's info in a webbrowser.

(Maybe with javascript or something.)

Answer (score 0):

I did custom implement that auto-fill feature, would like to share

use it with

```
let data = AutoFillData(fName: "Jhon")
webView.evaluateJavaScript(data.createJSString(), completionHandler: nil)
```

It searches dom elements with name and id

```
struct AutoFillData {
    var fName: String?
    var lName: String?
    var email: String?
    var phone: String?
    var shipAddress: String?
    var shipCity: String?
    var shipState: String?
    var shipCountry: String?
    var zip: String?

    enum KeyNames: String, CaseIterable {
        case first_name, customerFirstName,
             last_name, customerLastName,
             name,
             email, customerEmail,
             phone, alternatePhone, phoneNumber, phoneNumber2 = "phone-number",
             shipAddress = "ship-address", addressLine1, addressLine2,
             shipCity = "ship-city", city,
             shipState = "ship-state", state,
             shipZip = "ship-zip", zip, pincode,
             shipCountry = "ship-country", country
    }

    func getData(keyName: KeyNames) -> String? {
        switch keyName {
        case .first_name, .customerFirstName: return fName
        case .last_name, .customerLastName: return lName
        case .name: return [fName, lName].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
        case .email, .customerEmail: return email
        case .phone, .alternatePhone, .phoneNumber, .phoneNumber2: return phone
        case .shipAddress, .addressLine1, .addressLine2: return shipAddress
        case .shipCity, .city: return shipCity
        case .shipState, .state: return shipState
        case .shipCountry, .country: return shipCountry
        case .zip, .shipZip, .pincode: return zip
        }
    }

    func createJSString() -> String {
        var str = ""
        KeyNames.allCases.forEach {
            let value = getData(keyName: $0)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""
            if !value.isEmpty {
                str.append("""
                var e = document.getElementsByName('\($0.rawValue)')[0];
                if (e == null) {
                    e = document.getElementById('\($0.rawValue)');
                }
                if (e != null) {
                    e.value = '\(value)';
                }
                """)
            }
        }
        return str
    }
}
```